# How to create a collection class containing list of abstract elements

Tags: c#, list, collections, derived-class

I need to create a collection to containing a list of abstract segments.

I have a number of derived classes from segment i.e. `LineSegment : Segment`

```
public class Path : IEnumerable
{
        private List<Segment> segments = new List<Segment>();


        public List<Segment> Segments 
        {  
            set { Segments = value;}
            get { return this.segments; } 
        }
        //some code inc ctrs

}
```

I'd like to be able to define `LinePath` as a derived class from base class `Path`

```
public class LinePath : Path, IEnumerable
{        
        public LinePath(List<LineSegment> s)
        {
            this.Segments = s; //error
        }
}
```

However I keep running into situations where I can't easily edit the contains of a `LinePath` because of the list it contains still being a `Segment` list (lots of casting) or when I wish to create a normal `Path` from a `LinePath` plus other derived segments.

What would be a standard format for this kind of problem? Maybe I should give up on `LinePath` and just work with `Path` objects?

I realise there may be a slight vagueness to this question, I apologise for this but need to get a handle on what actually is causing me confusion and to avoid a messy solution.

Comment: One possibility is making `Path` generic, so it takes a `TSegment`

Comment: It is derived from Segment as mentioned.

Comment: @CodeInChaos I had it as generic previously and also got confused, would this help significantly to avoid lots of casting? I hadn't read this being one of the reasons for creating a generic collection.

Comment: You should take a step back and ask a question (perhaps over at codereview.stackexchange.com) that details your plan for architecting your classes. You keep running into issues because you have not given the issue enough thought before starting to write code.

Comment: Also, asking a broader question will help you get the correct answers. Right now you are focusing on just one small issue and there is no way someone can give you an answer that will play well with the *other* parts of your code because we have not seen it and you have not described it.

Comment: That could very well be true. Maybe i need to sit down with a pencil and paper and come back to the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a couple of options.  First, look for opportunities to use your list as `IEnumerable<T>` rather than `List<T>`, because a `List<LineSegment>` *can* be used as an `IEnumerable<Segment>` just by casting the list, without casting all the elements (assuming C# 4.0 or later).

Second, consider making Path derive from Segment (`PathSegment` if you will), so you can include a LinePath in a Path as a single object, rather than by adding all of its LineSegment elements to the Path's list of Segment elements.

You might want to post a larger excerpt of your code on codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Is it not possible to cast to IList<Segment> also? If not, why is it possible to IEnumerable<Segment>?

Comment: Because `IEnumerable<T>` is "covariant in T" -- it's actually declared as `IEnumerable<out T>`.  `IList<T>` cannot be covariant in T because it uses T as an input parameter, which means that if it were covariant, it would not be type safe.

Comment: Sorry I'm just a mere scientist/engineer not a computer scientist. Think i need to ask a broad question on the best place to learn some computer science concepts. i.e. 'covariant'!

Comment: @gwizardry covariance is the cause of a lot of confusion.  Search for it on Stack Overflow, or read Eric Lippert's blog posts: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/tags/Covariance+and+Contravariance/

Comment: Got it! I now understand what a IEnumerable implementing sequence is and I can see that because List is a 'List' and thus has not read only it is not covariant. Now i just need to apply this understanding to a clear and clever class definition architecture.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know wheter I understand the question properly, but I think this is the behaviour you want.

```
public class GenericPath<T> : IEnumerable
    {
        private List<T> items = new List<T>();


        public List<T> Items
        {
            set { this.items = value; }
            get { return this.items; }
        }
        //some code inc ctrs

    }

    public class Segment
    {
    }

    public class Path : GenericPath<Segment>
    {        

    }

    public class LinePath : GenericPath<Path>
    {
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think its better to define that generic parameter T should be of Segment type. To avoid something like `Path<string>`.

Also you don't need to inherit LinePath from IEnumerable - it will inherit this interface implementation from Path. And consider to use generic version of IEnumerable interface.

```
  public class Path<T> : IEnumerable<T>
        where T : Segment // here we define that parameter is Segment or its child
    {
        private List<T> _segments = new List<T>();        

        public List<T> Segments
        {
            set { _segments = value; }
            get { return _segments; }
        }

        public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public class LinePath<T> : Path<T> 
        where T : LineSegment // parameter is LineSegment or its child
    {

        public LinePath(List<T> segments)
        {
            // no error because Path.Segments of type List<LineSegment>
            Segments = segments;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I had something like this before except i didn't have where T : LineSegment for the LinePath, maybe that is the key to making it work using a generic Path

Comment: It should work without 'when' also. When just narrows types objects which could be used as parameters of class and gives you pretty intellysence inside parametrized class. BTW with generics no casting occurs. You just have different classes at runtime.